# Copying a texture's colors to a new texture to create a new sprite

Tags: c#, unity, textures

Let `mySprite` be some .PNG sprite:

```
Texture2D tex = mySprite.texture;
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0,0,tex.width,tex.height),new Vector2(0.0f,0.0f),1.0f);
```

The resulting sprite can be used by a `SpriteRenderer` just fine. Now, let's do something a bit more redundant:

```
Texture2D tex = mySprite.texture;
Texture2D tex2 = new Texture2D(tex.width,tex.height);
Color[] colors = tex.GetPixels(0,0,tex.width,tex.height);
tex2.SetPixels(colors);
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex2, new Rect(0,0,tex.width,tex.height),new Vector2(0.0f,0.0f),1.0f);
```

All I am doing is create a new texture, copy the original texture's colors, and then used this new texture to create my sprite. However, when I use this sprite with a `SpriteRenderer`, all I get is a grayish rectangle.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. You have to use

```
tex2.Apply();
```

For the `SetPixel()` changes to take effect.